# How do I decide the content and boundaries when organizing code into Javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, module, software-design, module-pattern

I'm working on improving the readability and modularity of my web app's code and I want to work on isolating code into modules. However, the biggest problem I'm running into is how to decide what goes in which module. Some are obvious, like a navigation module, but others are less clear. The biggest reason I have large `.js` file is because everything is extremely connected so different types of functions rely on access to variables larger in scope than its function block or even a potential module scope. This may actually be a sign of bad code and point towards the need to refactor.

Comment: Use a module system like Webpack.

Comment: @SLaks This more of a theoretical question. I know about webpack, module-pattern, etc. I'm more asking from a software-design perspective regarding how to determine the content of the modules themselves. How do we split up a web app into modules in a way that makes sense.

Comment: How to decide? Experience. "*Everything is extremely connected so different types of functions rely on access to variables larger in scope than its function block or even a potential module scope*" - yes, [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) may definitely be a sign of bad code. Break them up into smaller components,  then put those in their own modules (if you want - large file sizes are not necessarily an issue itself).